# Meteor/React Mocha tests using Enzyme - Cannot find module 'has'

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

As Stated i'm running a Meteor Application with React, and starting to write test with Mocha. Currently I have a basic test that tests nothing.

**client/prospects/ProspectForm.tests.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<Foo />', () => {

  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
  });

});
```

When I startup my test server I get the following error

[image: error]

Cannot find module 'has'. It looks like the problem is originating from enzyme, but when I create a new meteor application and add enzyme and practicalmeteor:mocha, and then add the same test it works fine, so it must have something to do with my environment on this app.

Here is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "myApp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.27.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-mounter": "^1.2.0",
    "react-s-alert": "^1.1.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

and here is my meteor packages file

```
# edgee:slingshot                         # Send files to storage service.
# peerlibrary:aws-sdk                     # Amazon SDK for S3/EC2/etc...


# CORE PACKAGES
meteor-base                               # Meteor platform
mobile-experience                         # Mobile Optimizations
logging                                   # Meteor internal logging
ejson                                     # Extends JSON Types
tracker                                   # Reactive Data Sources
email                                     # Send emails
accounts-password                         # Authentication for users.
es5-shim                                  # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript                                # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax
standard-minifier-css                     # CSS Minification
standard-minifier-js                      # Javascript Minification
static-html                               # Adds global head tag
reload                                    # Active reload
react-meteor-data                         # Used for react data mixins

stevezhu:lodash                           # Javascript utility library.
momentjs:moment                           # Date library for Javascript.
johnantoni:meteor-normalize               # normalizes css
fourseven:scss                            # SASS stylesheets.
fortawesome:fontawesome                   # Icons.
natestrauser:animate-css                  # Animations using CSS.
mongo                                     # Mongo DB
aldeed:collection2                        # Schemas and validations for database collections.
dburles:collection-helpers                # Create data helpers in ./lib available to client and server.
meteortoys:allthings                      # A number of helpers for deveopment. Activate with control+m
kadira:flow-router                        # Router.
mystor:device-detection                   # Detect device user is using.
semantic:ui-css
practicalmeteor:mocha
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also install [these 2 dependencies](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) if you don't already have them:

```
npm i --save-dev react-addons-test-utils
npm i --save-dev react-dom
```

Looks like you have react-dom, but you are missing the test-utils.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had done that awhile ago then I reset my branch and started over and forgot. It still didn't work with it, what ended up working was running meteor update.

Answer (score 0):

Running meteor update solved this for me, and I did have to do what Davin said as well.